# How do I pull a Docker image from one private registry (Docker hub) and push it to a second different private registry (AWS ECR) in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ecr

Need to build a Jenkins pipeline to pull Docker images from private registry (docker hub) & push it to destination private registry (AWS ECR).. Mainly how to define the parameters like source image/tag name from docker and target name/image and also how to configure the ECR authentication token as it expires every 12 hrs?

Comment: Would https://stackoverflow.com/a/62666653/6309 help?

Comment: VonC, Thanks for your answer. It looks more towards build and push it to ECR. what I am looking is to get the image from private docker hub and push it to AWS ECR using the same jenkins pipeline.