# Docker Image can't push to ECR via Jenkins Pipeline & docker.withRegistry

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-ecr

I am running jenkins on a aws server
Working on a pipeline for building docker images and push to ECR on the same aws account

```
def aws_account = "https://xxxxxx.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/"
def ecr_credentials = "iam-role-arn for ecr"


    docker.withRegistry(aws_account + "${ecr_repository_name}", "ecr:us-west-2:${ecr_credentials}") {
        docker.image(customImage).push()
    }
```

While pushing I am getting below error
tcp:lookup is pointing to the account number itself

**Error:**
**docker.service**
Mar 04 10:46:13 ip-x-xxx-x-xxx dockerd[921]: time="2021-03-04T10:46:13.989576275Z" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.41/auth returned error: Get https://yyyyyyy.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v2/: dial tcp: lookup yyyyyyy.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com: no such host"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name is wrong

> def aws_account = "https://xxxxxx.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/"

It should be something like

```sh
def aws_account = "https://1234567890.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
def ecr_credentials = "iam-role-arn for ecr"


    docker.withRegistry(aws_account + "${ecr_repository_name}", "ecr:us-west-2:${ecr_credentials}") {
        docker.image(customImage).push()
    }
```

[Pushing to ECR Using Jenkins Pipeline Plugin](https://blog.mikesir87.io/2016/04/pushing-to-ecr-using-jenkins-pipeline-plugin/)

[push-to-ecr-from-jenkins-pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59084989/push-to-ecr-from-jenkins-pipeline)